# multi-process in C : global variable's value

Tags: c, sockets, multiprocessing

Here is the code from a website. It used multi-processing to create a server. My question is: will the parent process close(newsockfd) executed before the child process doprocessing(newsockfd) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

void doprocessing (int sock);

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
   char buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int n, pid;

   /* First call to socket() function */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) {
      perror("ERROR opening socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Initialize socket structure */
   bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   portno = 5001;

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   /* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
   if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
      perror("ERROR on binding");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* Now start listening for the clients, here
      * process will go in sleep mode and will wait
      * for the incoming connection
   */

   listen(sockfd,5);
   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

   while (1) {
      newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

      if (newsockfd < 0) {
         perror("ERROR on accept");
         exit(1);
      }

      /* Create child process */
      pid = fork();

      if (pid < 0) {
         perror("ERROR on fork");
         exit(1);
      }

      if (pid == 0) {
         /* This is the client process */
         close(sockfd);
         doprocessing(newsockfd);
         exit(0);
      }
      else {
         close(newsockfd);
      }

   } /* end of while */
}

===-=================
void doprocessing (int sock) {
   int n;
   char buffer[256];
   bzero(buffer,256);
   n = read(sock,buffer,255);

   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR reading from socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
   n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);

   if (n < 0) {
      perror("ERROR writing to socket");
      exit(1);
   }

}
```

==========-==========================

code is from this website:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm

Answer (score 1):

When the process is forked, the gets a copy of the open set of file desriptors, and the reference count on the open filess is incremented accordingly. The `close` only happens *in the parent process*, so the child still maintains a reference to the open file. The order of execution doesn't really matter. On a multi-cpu system, it may happen truly simultaneously.

Global variables *are not* shared by forked child processes. A forked process runs in its own virtual memory space.

Comment: Should it be like:      if (pid == 0) {
         /* This is the client process */
         close(sockfd);
         doprocessing(newsockfd);      /* I added this close statement->  */ close(newsockfd);
         exit(0);
      }
      else {
         close(newsockfd);
      }

Comment: a file desriptor is a pointer? Why it's defined as an integer?

Comment: @user2373043 - A file descriptor is an integer. You are thinking of FILE pointers.

Comment: @alvits, as Jonathon Reinhart said "When the process is forked, the gets a copy of the open set of file desriptors, and the reference count on the open filess is incremented accordingly. " So how come an integer variable newsockfd can have reference? newsockfd is an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: When a child is forked, the child process will have a complete copy of everything a parent had. This is a complete copy, not a pointer to the parent. Any changes to the variables in the parent, including file descriptors, are local and doesn't affect the child.

Comment: @alvits, assume newsockfd = 5. In the parent process, close(5); it means the connection between the client and the server is closed, right?

Comment: You have to understand that the kernel is responsible for the majority of this behavior. The kernel maintains a set of open "file objects", and provides userspace with integer "file descriptors" which are used by the kernel to look up the file object during system calls. Multiple file descriptors (across different processes even) can refer to the same file object.

Comment: Your last comment indicates that you're not carefully reading my post. Again, when the process forks, there are now *two* references to that open connection: one in each the parent and child process. When the parent closes the socket, the reference count drops to 1. It's not until it goes to 0 that the socket is *actually* closed in the kernel.